# Хранить в базе значения времени до 1970 года?

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день, мне нужно делать из базы выборки по дню рождению, учитывая месяц и день. Т.е. допустим вытягивать тех, кому от 20 до 22 лет, учитывая сегодняшний день/месяц и день/месяц дня рождения юзера. Я не знаю.. может есть какая-то функция которая упрощает работу с этим делом, но единственное что мне пришло в голову - при вводе дня рождения - переводить эту дату в секунды и записывать в базу, а при выборе уже искать тех кто попадает в диапозон секунд между 20 и 22 годами. Но потом я вспомнил про то что отсчет то там ведется с 1970 года. Т.е. тех кто родился ранее перевести в секунды не получится.. значение будет толи отрицательное, толи ноль.. толи null, незнаю. Как можно выкрутиться из этой ситуации?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE date_born BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 22 YEAR) AND (NOW() - INTERVAL 20 YEAR)
```

Выберет всех чей возраст на данный момент 20-22 года.
Поле date_born - дата рождения. Тип - или DATE или DATETIME.

Comment: хм, спасибо, не знал про INTERVAL, сейчас почитаю о нем

Comment: а какой вариант будет быстрее:

тот что дали вы, либо такой..

    SELECT * FROM users WHERE date_born > 20 AND date_born < 22

?

Comment: По скорости - одинаково. По точности - мой вариант точнее. Я учитываю всю дату рождения относительно текущего момента, а вы - только год. Плюс, в моем варианте в качестве параметров задаются нижняя и верхняя возрастные границы, а в вашем вначале прийдется вычислить года рождения.

Comment: супер! спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table where MONTH(date)='12' and DAY(date)='28' and YEAR(date)='1957'
```

выберет пользователей которые родились 28 декабря 1957 года. **date** поле типа DATE

**upd:**

чтобы выбрать 20-ти летних можно воспльзоваться конструкцией:

```
YEAR(NOW())-YEAR(date)='20'
```

но лучше в запросе использовать год рождения, как написал в первом примере.

Comment: мне диапозон нужен, например вывести всех что с 20 по 25 лет

Comment: @FLK, функции в левом операнде условия использовать крайне не желательно. Это сводит на нет возможность использовать индекс.